# Why is that some Base64 string where successfully sent and others are not?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'ved been trying to send some Base64 strings to codebehind, some images that I converted where successfully sent to codebehind but some where not..

Heres the js function that im using for convertion..

```
function readFile() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var FR = new FileReader();

        FR.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("imagebase64", e.target.result);
            console.log(e.target.result);
            alert(e.target.result);
        });

        FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
}
```

heres the ajax post

```
var DTO = { 'base64File' : image};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "../../../Operation/requestEvent.aspx/createEvent",
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (result) {

        if (result.d <= 0) {
            //false alert something 
            alert("FALSE");
        }
        else if (result.d > 0) {
            //true
            alert("true");
        }
        else {
            alert(result.d);
        }
        console.log(result.d);
    },
    error: function (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, errorthrown) {
        alert(" connection to the server failed ");
        console.log("error: " + errorthrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just throwing out ideas as I don't know how you're actually sending the data, but is it possible that the Base64 encoded string also needs to be URL encoded? (Based off of a GET verb)

Comment: I used ajax / json Post for sending the Base64...

Comment: I don't think your question contains enough information for us to offer solutions.  What happens with a base64 string that isn't sent successfully?  What error are you getting, and where are you getting it?

Comment: @Warren what are the contents of `errorthrown` when the error:function triggers?

Comment: uhm.. I included an alert(" connection to the server failed ") to test if the post request was successful , tho some images where sent successfully but some where not...

Comment: @Warren That isn't helpful.  Right after that line you are sending `errorthrown` to the console.  What error are you getting?

Comment: oh im sorry.. the error was Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @Warren A 500 error indicates a server-side error in your C# code invoked by `../../../Operation/requestEvent.aspx/createEvent`.

Comment: thank you,
this seem to happen to some particular Base64 converted images... I'm just wondering what causes  this kind of error?

Comment: @Warren A 500 error is equivalent to your server saying "Hey, I messed up."  It indicates only that something is wrong, and does not give *any* indication of the nature of the underlying issue.  It's like the "check engine" light on your car.  Check your server side logs and debug that method, and add the C# code here if you still need help.

Comment: Thank you for helping.. I'll check the logs, and be back if I still have questions.. :)